# When is an insert checked for errors

Tags: trigger, data-loader

In a dataloader I want to insert information into the database. This information has a lookup with a different ID than the Salesforce ID. What I want to do is run a before insert trigger that checks all accounts that have the same (unique) ID and then take their SF Id and point it to the insert information that is being inserted.
Unfortunately, my insert fails before my trigger is even fired so my question is+ is there a way to first run my trigger and THEN check for errors when inserting with the Dataloader?

Comment: What dataloader error are you getting?  Normally, Data Loader operations are no different than UI operations (except they occur in bulk) - before insert executes, then validation rules, then after insert, then workflows (see Order of Execution)

Comment: Do you mean that you are loading an invalid value into a Lookup? Like instead of Account__c = '001000000000001' you are loading Account__c = 'MYVALUE789' and then you want a trigger to find which Account is 'MYVALUE789' and put its ID into Account__c?